# Update + join from two databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Help me create an sql query.
There are two databases DB1 and DB2. In each of them there are tables "users" and "cities" with the names of cities. Users and city names are the same in both databases. But the city ID values are different in the two databases. In the first DB1 database, the "users" table contains the city IDs from the "cities" table.
I need to update the city data in the second DB2 database. For each "users" value from DB1, find the name "cities" and update the values in DB2.users. The problem is that the city ID values are different in the two databases. Only the names are the same.

[image: Databases structure]

Comment: From site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Homework question? Where is your attempt at this?

Comment: You know that you don't have to join by ID. You can join by names too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an update with join:

```
update DB2.users set
city = DB2.cities.ID
from DB2.users 
join DB1.users on DB1.users.ID = DB2.users.ID
join DB1.cities on DB1.cities.ID = DB1.users.city
join DB2.cities on DB2.cities.name = DB1.cities.name
```

The join from DB2.users to DB2.cities goes via DB1's tables, going over using user ID and coming back using city name.

Answer (score 0):

```
A and B beign the 2 databases       

with cte as(
        select DB1.ID, DB1.UserName, (select Name from A.dbo.tbl_Cities where Id= DB1.CITY) as 'City'
        from A.dbo.tbl_Users as DB1)
        select DB2.ID,DB2.UserName,cte.City  from B.dbo.tbl_users as DB2  inner join cte on DB2.ID= cte.ID 
    inner join B.dbo.tbl_Cities as DB2Cities on cte.City= DB2Cities.Name
```